# Not able to make mergDatagridScroller running

Tags: android, ios, datagrid, livecode

sorry for asking this question which seems perhaps stupid to the one or other...

As I need a native-scrolling Datagrid on iOS and Android, I downloaded mergDatagridScroller 1.3 and started to try it out, but did not come over the fourth hurdle.

1. I installed droptools - this worked
2. I put mergDatagridScroller into the Plugin-Folger - worked

3a. I made a new stack and placed a mergDatagridScroller on it - worked

3b. I opened the stack mergDatagridScroller which was delivered with the package

4. I tried to exchange the datagrid in 3a. and 3b. with one of my own ones as described in the readme - but here I was completely unseccessful. I divided the mergdatagrid into all its parts, I threw it away and pasted my own onto the stack, I called the command updateContentRect, but nothing happened.

How is it done correctly ?